# Logic: Same premises and different conclusion?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Suppose that there are $n$ premises, say $p_1,\cdots, p_n$.
Then, is it possible to obtain two different conclusion?
That is, Can we obtain two conclusions $q_1$ and $q_2$ using the rule of inferences if we have the same premises $p_1,\cdots, p_n$?

For example, if $p_1 \rightarrow p_2$ and $p_2 \rightarrow p_3$, then the rule of inferences says that $p_1 \rightarrow p_3$ is valid. In this situation, can we get another valid argument?

Comment: Can we derive only one theorem from the axioms of group theory?

Comment: @miracle173 Sorry, what does it mean? You mean that we can get several valid argument. right?

Comment: Yes; everi $p_i$ follows from the set of premises.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example, if $p_1 \rightarrow p_2$ and $p_2 \rightarrow p_3$, then the rule of inferences says that $p_1 \rightarrow p_3$ is valid. In this situation, can we get another valid argument?

Sure. Since $$(A→B) ∧ (B→C) \implies (A∧B → C) ∧ (A→C),$$ the arguments $$A→C\tag{A1}$$ and $$A∧B → C\tag{A2}$$ are both derivable from the premises $$A→B$$ and $$B→C.$$ Furthermore, since $$(A∧B→C) \kern.8em\not\kern-.8em\iff (A→C),$$ arguments $(A1)$ and $(A2)$ are not logically equivalent.

Comment: Thank you for your comments

Comment: Can I ask one more question? If the conclusion is a conditional statement such as $p_1 \rightarrow p_3$ in the above example, then can we assume that $p_1$ is true to show that the argument is valid?

Comment: @filterhash 1. Remember, [it is the soundness—not the validity—of $A\to C$ that depends on $A$'s truth](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4420694/21813). $\quad$ 2. If this is just propositional logic, then [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4234427/21813) previous Answer that I wrote gives one method for verifying the validity of argument $A\to C.$ $\quad$ 3. If $A$ and $C$ are both atomic propositions, that $A\to C$ must be invalid. (Why?)

Comment: Thanks! Actually, based on my understanding, we do not assume that $p_1$ is true. If $p_1$ is true, then valid argument is $r$ in my example. Thus, I thought it implies the contradiction before the this question.

Comment: Thanks. My last exercise is to show that $A\rightarrow C$ is invalid.

Comment: Also: [Valid argument? Sound argument?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4232127/21813).